# System call moving Stack Pointer?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64

I am learning x86-64 assembly. I am trying to write some "shellcode".

In the beginning I backup all the registers (I put 123 into `rdi` so that I know I am doing everything right in the end)

```
mov     rdi, 123
push    rdi
push    rsi
push    rdx
push    rcx
```

Then I prepare an array of arguments for the syscall `execve` on the stack. I just `push` pointers (all as `qword`) to `0x00`, `/usr/bin/touch AAA`, `-c` and `/bin/sh` and then I call `execve` with address of `rsp` in `rsi`. The program works as expected.

But then I `pop` the register values I pushed earlier and call `sys_exit` with the value 123 that should now be in `rdi` where I put it in the beginning.

```
; pop 4 times - the pointers for execve
pop     rax
pop     rax
pop     rax
pop     rax

; pop the backed up registers
pop     rcx
pop     rdx
pop     rsi
pop     rdi

; call EXIT with exit code in rdi
mov rax, 60
syscall
```

When I execute the code, it works as expected, but after executing `echo $?` the output is `0`.

However if I comment out the `syscall` command from where I call `execve`, the output of `echo $?` is `123` as it should be.

When I try to see what is happening in `gdb`, it is complaining that I am running another process from my program (breakpoint 1 was at the beginning of the program, breakpoint 2 on `mov rax, 60` at the end):

```
process 10140 is executing new program: /bin/dash
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: No source file named /home/...
Error in re-setting breakpoint 2: No source file named /home/...
[Inferior 1 (process 10140) exited normally]
```

Why is the code behaving like this? Why does the system call to `execve /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/touch AAA` change the stack of my program and how do I restore the registers properly?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You do realize `execve` replaces your program in memory with the one you launch, right? So it will not continue to execute. See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) in particular that _"execve() does not return on success, and the text, initialized data, uninitialized data (bss), and stack of the calling process are overwritten according to the contents of the newly loaded program."_

Comment: I see, `execve` seems to work as designed.

Comment: I must have been blind, thank you very much... I don't know why but I thought that execve forks automatically and the command is executed by the child.